# strange behaviour with custom hooks

Tags: react-hooks

I've made custom axios hook.

```
// src/useAxios.js

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAxios = url => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null, loading: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(currentState => ({
            ...currentState,
            loading: true
        }));

        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            setState(currentState => ({
                ...currentState
                data: response.data.body
            }));
        });

        setState(currentState => ({
            ...currentState,
            loading: false
        }));
    }, [url]);

    return state;
};
```

App component uses this hook.

```
// src/App.js    

import React from 'react';
import { useAxios } from './useAxios';

const App = () => {
    const { data, loading } = useAxios(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    );
    console.log(loading);

    return <div>{loading ? 'loading..' : data}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

I've added `console.log` to the App component to check how it works.

And it logs `false false false`.

What I expected was `false true true false`, since variable loading is changing four times.

But If I change the hook like below, it logs `false true false` correctly.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAxios = url => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null, loading: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(currentState => ({
            ...currentState,
            loading: true
        }));

        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            setState(currentState => ({
                loading: false,
                data: response.data.body
            }));
        });
    }, [url]);

    return state;
};
```

What is the problem?

Can't we use `useState` more than twice in the `useEffect`?

What is wrong with the first hook?

Answer (score 0):

It was fool to ask this.

The reason why the first one logs "false false false" is that

since setState batched together, so true cannot be logged.

And I've made fatal mistake that I've used useState after the promise, not inside of it.

Here is the right code.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const useAxios = url => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null, loading: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState(currentState => ({
            ...currentState,
            loading: true
        }));

        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            setState(currentState => ({
                ...currentState,
                data: response.data.body
            }));

            setState(currentState => ({
                ...currentState,
                loading: false
            }));
        });
    }, [url]);

    return state;
};
```

It logs false true true false as I've expected